# Check for pending changes when using WPF Explicit Binding

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have a modal popup that contains a CheckBox that uses Explicit binding to update binding source when the user clicks the save button on form.

```
<CheckBox Content="Default" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Unit.IsDefault, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit"/>
```

Now I want to add a cancel button to the form, if the user clicks it I'd like to check if there are any pending binding updates and, if so, show the user a message.

Is this possible to do with bindings?  I'm hoping for something like:

```
BindingExpression binding = cb.GetBindingExpression(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty);
binding.HasPendingUpdates(); // Anything similar to this?
```

Failing that does anyone have any other suggestions on how to keep track of changes to bindings that haven't been explicitly updated yet?

Comment: Have you tried comparing the current value with the source value?

Comment: I considered doing that, and still could do if required, but I was wondering if there's a built in way of doing it which would save me time and effort.

Answer (score 1):

As Kurian pointed out, the property `IsDirty` on `BindingExpressionBase` can be used if you are using .NET 4.5.

In the meantime, a workaround could be to check the **internal** property `NeedsUpdate` using reflection:

```
public static bool IsDirty(this BindingExpression binding)
{
    if (binding == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("binding");

    var needsUpdateProperty = typeof(BindingExpressionBase).GetProperty("NeedsUpdate", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    var isDirtyAsObject = needsUpdateProperty.GetValue(binding, null);
    if (isDirtyAsObject is bool)
        return (bool)isDirtyAsObject;

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a convert. Add some property IsSuspended and HasPendingChanges to the converter. When IsSuspended is true then return Binding.DoNothing() from the converter and set HasPendingChanges to true inside converter. Otherwise return the original value and set HasPendingChanges to false.

At declaration of this converter in xaml set IsSuspended to true. When user click on button first check HasPendingChanges and then set IsSuspended to false and update binding. after update revert IsSuspended to true.

Comment: I presume you're meaning a MultiValueConverter if you're talking about adding properties (IsSuspended + HasPendingChanges?). Wouldn't the converter only be used when binding is updated?

Answer (score 0):

defaultCheckBox.GetBindingExpression(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty).IsDirty